# How to make aiogram 3 filter to enable in handler only one command or without any command execution

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Need to make a dispatcher filter to execute a code only if message.text has inside a specified command or doesn't have any command.

I have tried this and many others combinations of aiogram 3 F:

```
@dp.message(F.text and (~(F.entities[...].type == MessageEntityType.BOT_COMMAND) or F.text.startswith("/mycommand")))
```

but it doesn't work properly.

Any suggestions? How to mix F filter parameters correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from aiogram.filters import Command, or_f


@dp.message(or_f(Command("mycommand"), ~F.text.startswith('/')))
```

The filter is composed using the or_f function, which combines multiple filters with a logical OR operator.
The filters applied are:

- `Command("mycommand")`: Matches messages that are commands and
  specifically starts with "mycommand".
- `~F.text.startswith('/')`:
  Matches messages that do not start with a forward slash ("/"),
  indicating they are not commands.

Overall, this filter is designed to capture messages that either match the command "mycommand" or are not traditional command messages.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
The other way is not so convenient but work too is to use right sequencing.

`@dp.message(Command("mycommand"))`
`@dp.message(F.text & ~F.text.startswith('/'))`
`async def handler(...): ...`

At the end of the article some pictures:
https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/router.html